# How do I write to textField.tag = 15 from within an other method?

Tags: tags, xcode4.5

This code draws a number of text fields and assigns a tag and writes the tag number to each. How can I write say an "X" to the textfield with tag number 15?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    int z = 0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int y = 10; y < 300; y = y + 25)
    {
        for (int x = 10; x < 300; x = x + 25)
        {
            textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 25, 25)];
            textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
            textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:16];
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            textField.enabled = NO;            
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", z];
            [self.view addSubview:textField];
            textField.tag = z++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the right text field by calling `viewWithTag`:

```
UITextField *myField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:15];
// Now that I have my field, I can write some text into it:
myField.text = @"X";
```